# Difference of the usage of past simple and present perfect tense

Tags: word-usage

What is the exact difference between-'i had breakfast' and ' i have had breakfast'?
What are the precise meanings these convey and how do they differ?

Comment: Or *I breakfasted* and *I have breakfasted*?

Comment: Simple past just talks about an event that occurred.  Present perfect makes a statement about your present condition: you are in a state of having had breakfast- and are probably not hungry right now